# Is it 'Batmen' or 'Batmans'?

Tags: dc, batman

If Batman met a clone of himself or a Batman from an alternate dimension, would we say:

> There are two Batmen

or

> There are two Batmans

You'd assume *Batmen* but Batman is his name, not his title.

Have we ever seen any examples in canon?

Comment: *Holy Batmen, Batman; there's two Batmans!*

Comment: @daft you mean bat bats?

Comment: @CanadianLuke lol... yeah I think you're right.

Comment: Perhaps it's like sheep. One Batman, a group of Batman, many Batman

Comment: I’m fairly sure it’s Batsman.

Comment: In German it would definitely be "Batmans", but that doesn't count, does it? ;-)

Comment: @DevSolar: *[Die Fledermaus!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tick_(comics)#Main_characters)*

Comment: @DevSolar in Soviet Russia, man bats you!

Comment: It's "there are 2 Batman" or "There are 2 copies of Batman" :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/), or [Linguistics Stack Exchange](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @Lexible it's a fantasy name from a fantasy universe. They'd close it as off-topic over there for sure.

Comment: According to the Dark Knight film, it's Batman and a bunch of guys wearing hockey pads

Comment: Yeah, it’s time for linguistics-in-fantasy.stackexchange.com…

Comment: “Batman is his name, not his title” — are we sure about that?

Comment: @ryan: Two copies would make three batmen... ;-)

Comment: "Why would you mess with the Batmans?" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-2EikOsQmtk

Comment: @PaulD.Waite [let's ask the man himself...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4xbbpH-20ak)

Comment: @InguShama: is his name also “Vengeance” and “The Night”?

Comment: @DevSolar you are correct sir, I concede:)

Comment: Thinking outside the box here, but it kind of feels right: *Batmannen*?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This issue of [Superman/Batman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superman/Batman) is called:

> [Supermen/Batmen](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Superman/Batman_Vol_1_25)

So I'd have to assume that's the correct way to say it.

Grammatically, *Batmans* might actually be correct since it's his name and not his title, like you say. But *Batmans* just sounds wrong.

Comment: There is one Batman, and one poser?

Comment: @Daft:   Disagree with the final sentence.   He is known as THE Batman.   Therefore, Batman is noun and can support any plural.  Furthermore, there's probably a legitimate argument that building a compound word out of two nouns "normally" will take the plural based on the plural of the final noun.

Comment: @ThePopMachine that's why I qualified it with _might_, because I really wasn't sure.

Comment: @ThePopMachine [He calls himself Batman](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4xbbpH-20ak)... So who's wrong here, you or Batman?

Comment: @InguShama:  When you say "There are two Batmen/Batmans" you are really using it as a noun with a meaning, not a name (which is also a noun, I know).   It's not the same as saying "There are two Johnsons" where you are focusing on the name, not what the word means.

Comment: See @JanusBahsJacquet 's comment below.

Comment: @ThePopMachine I don't really care enough to Google the words in his comment I don't understand. Daft's answer is perfectly acceptable to me. I was just curious so I thought I'd ask. Honestly I was hoping someone would dig up a _Batmans_ from somewhere!

Answer (score 18):

There is a group of "Batmen" in Superman - Red Son. It is never referred to as "Batmans".

[image: Superman - Red Son, Pt. 3]

Comment: Isn't that a group referring to themselves as "The Batmen", though?  That's different from multiple people who are each referred to as "The Batman" - the plural for the latter would be "The Batmans", I think.

Answer (score 1):

There have in fact been multiple occasions in the comics where Batmen was used as the plural form of Batman, one such instance being the "Batmen of All Nations".

As a footnote, aside from instances in which the Bruce Waynes of multiple dimensions have encountered each other, there have been several individuals to take up the mantle of Batman over the years in various continuities, such as Jean Paul Valley, Dick Grayson, and Terry McGinnis.

Answer (score 1):

Grammatically, while Batman is *used* like a proper noun, its derivation is a descriptive conjunction of two common nouns, formed in such a way that the noun "bat" serves like an adjective as a descriptive modifier to the common noun "man," because, well... we can skip that explanation right? Oh good.

So it is in fact totally fine to use the common plural of "man" (e.g., "men") and conjoin that once again with "bat" to arrive at "Batmen." We even have other answers here showing that this is a canonically accepted form.

But one consideration that no one has met is that the idea of many Batmen is slightly ludicrous. And "Batman" does indeed serve as a proper noun contextually. Thus, "Batmans" may actually be the right wording in *particular contexts* when wanting to call attention to the comical nature it may invoke, given how—technically correct or not—clumsily wrong it *sounds*.

Example:

"There is a bevy of Batmans headed our way! What is this I don't even?"

Answer (score 0):

Batman is a proper noun so you will pluralize the full noun rather than use the plural of 'man'.  So 'Batmans' is actually correct.  This is similar to Brother-in-laws (instead of brothers-in-law) or Book of Mormons (instead of Books of Mormon).

Comment: Except that it actually is "brothers-in-law"...

Comment: @corsiKa, not the [movie](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4000956/). But yes, you are correct.

Comment: Your off on the Book of Mormon, it's actually "there are multiple copies of the Book of Mormon" since the Book of Mormon is actually a collection of books already. See http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/168815/what-is-the-plural-for-the-book-of-mormon

Comment: This is quite simply not correct. Just because something is a proper name does not mean that you automatically have to pluralise it by simply tacking -s on to the end of the entire noun phrase. Man of Steel is also a proper noun, but there is no doubt whatsoever that its plural would be Men of Steel, not *Man of Steels. The name Batman is completely transparently perceived as a determinative (and thus endocentric) compound noun with man as its head noun, and there is nothing to indicate that its plural would naturally be anything but Batmen.

Comment: Although consensus seems to indicate I was wrong, and that brothers-in-law is more correct, there are those that argue brother-in-laws is also correct. http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/plural-of-brother-in-law.846253/ @ryan: While we can often re-structure our sentences to get around saying things that are ambiguous or sound incorrect, the fact that it is a compilation of other books has nothing to do with how we pluralize something and 'Book of Mormons' is in fact the correct pluralization of said book.  Just as 'I have 14 Moby Dicks!' sounds strange, that does not make it incorrect.

Comment: @Janus If you are using "Men of Steel" to refer to a group of hard men (such as the Pittsburgh Steelers) I will agree with you.  However, If there were a knock-off superman action figure called "Man of Stihl" being given to kids in an attempt to sell their parents power tools.  If my kid had 12 of them and wanted to ask me if he could bring all of them to the hardware store with us and he said "Dad can I bring my 'Man of Stihl's?" he will have earned 2 gold stars.  Because you can't just change somethings proper name just to make it 'sound' right.  That is what I am getting at.

Comment: @krayzk, if you need to resort to manufacturing homonyms to preserve your argument, you might consider conceding the point.

Comment: @TheFontSnob Manufacturing homonyms is very relevant here.  The question posed is "Is it 'Batmen' or 'Batmans'?"  I am pointing out that if the entirety of the phrase is the noun you are trying to pluralize then you pluralize the entirety, you don't pick out the word that 'sounds the most correct' and pluralize that to appease your ear.  Janus's example was flawed because both 'Man of Steel' and 'Men of Steel' have been used as titles for many different things. I simplified it for him with a 'homonym' that could not be mistaken for anything but what it was, and better applied to the question.