# What works are these Batmen from?

Tags: story-identification, dc, batman

[image: bat-image]

What works (or story lines) are each of these different versions of Batman from?

Comment: They are from *Batman*.... DUH

Comment: 11 Batmen...sure it's not a cricket team?

Comment: “Batmen” — it‘s actually [*Batsman*](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/99599/is-it-batmen-or-batmans/99627#comment229094_99599).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. From *Batman* (Michael Keaton's Batman)
2. From *The Dark Knight Returns* (Frank Miller)
3. From *Batman Begins* (Christian Bale's Batman)
4. From *The New Batman Adventures*, the sequel series to *Batman: The Animated Series*
5. From *Batman: Arkham Asylum* video game series
6. The Bat-Man, From *Detective Comics* in the 1930s.
7. Some version of Batman from the 1970s, possibly the *Superfriends* animated series
8. Prime-Earth Batman (DC comics New 52, 2011+)
9. From *Batman: The Brave and The Bold* animated series
10. From *Batman*, the 60's show (Adam West's Batman)
11. From *Batman: The Long Halloween* (or one of Tim Sale's other books)

Comment: #3 is actually from 2nd or 3rd movie, since the armour is plated.

Comment: @Gallifreyan And the head can move better. The first movie’s suit (Begins) restricted head movements so much that Bale started neck pain.