# Why are there 2 Spider-Men in this picture?

Tags: marvel, history-of, spider-man, meme

I've seen this picture on social media and was wondering why there are 2 Spider-Man (Spider-Men?). What's the storyline of this issue?

[image]

Comment: That's his evil twin, Spoderman

Comment: I believe the plural of Spider-Man is [*Spider-Mannen*](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/99599/is-it-batmen-or-batmans).

Comment: One is clearly [Spider-Man 2099](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oscar_Isaac).

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This is not from an issue of any of the comics. It's from an episode of the 1967 cartoon.

In the episode *Double Identity* (S01E19B), an actor turned crook named Charles Cameo is impersonating Spider-Man (and others) while robbing people. Spider-Man, of course, confronts the crook and ends up catching him.