# Spider-Man and Fantastic 4 crossover comic with Double Identity Scene

Tags: story-identification, marvel, comics, spider-man, fantastic-four

I recently found [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/163051/why-are-there-2-spider-men-in-this-picture) while browsing the site, and the accepted answer says the image never came from the comic books. However, I clearly remember that my first comic book issue had that exact scene. I've been looking for it ever since, but I haven't had any luck yet. It was a Spider-Man and Fantastic 4 Crossover.

- Media: Comic Book
- When I read it: 2006-2008
- Tone: Humorous/light-hearted
- Setting: NYC, Baxter building(?)
- Characters: Spider-Man, Fake Spider-Man, Fantastic 4, Baxter Building receptionist
- Language: English

What I remember:

- Spider-Man goes to the Baxter building to apply to the F4. He gives a long-winded introduction to the receptionist and says she can address him by any or all of those names. She responds with something along the lines of "Alright, have a seat in the waiting area, Mister Man." (Burn)
- Image of Spidey pointing at Spidey, with none of the police able to tell the two apart (in linked question.)
- Johnny gets an epiphany and grabs both spiders (without burning either of them) before dropping them off of a tall building. Peter shoots a web to safety, but the imposter doesn't have webs, so he starts screaming and flailing. Torch delivers him to the police.
- The last panel featured a Q&A with the illustrator. One reader noticed that there were some very subtle differences between the 2 suits and asked if that was deliberate. The illustrator confirmed that it was indeed intentional so astute readers could tell who the fake was.

What it's not: [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Man_and_the_Fantastic_Four) from 2007.

Comment: it's fair to say though that the linked question / answer is correct - since the accepted answer here was from 2006, and the "pointing spiderman" image in the linked question is from an old 60's era cartoon, its possible that there was no comic PRIOR to that cartoon that the show would have been taking the image / idea from. But - that's not what the answer says anyway - it merely says that the image in the question isn't from a comic, but from the show. There may indeed have been duplicate Spider-Men seen in the comics prior to that episode

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is [*Spider-Man Team-Up #1 - Fantastic Four: **The Chameleon Strikes!***](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1322700.Spider_Man_Team_Up) from 2006.

He encounters a shirty receptionist.

[image]

This is the *doppelganger* scene

[image]

And the resolution. It's not Johnny that throws the spiders, it's Ben. Torch does catch the imposter though.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Do you have the direct link to the TV Tropes page? Their search is as bad as Reddit's sometimes.

Comment: @jinkevin - https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Funny/SpiderMan?from=Funny.Spider-Man